# Can I use category slug in wordpress page url?

Tags: wordpress, categories, slug

Can I use category slug in wordpress page url? I would like the following url structure for the pages:

```
/%category%/%postname% => http://example.org/category/pagename
```

This working properly with post content, but doesn't work with pages.

Any idea?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Custom Post Type Permalinks plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/) to manually adjust the permalink structure of your pages.

Set pages to use `/%postname%` and your posts to use `/%category%/%postname%`

Since your pages don't have categories, it doesn't make sense to include them in the URL. Also, be careful when including the category in your permalink structure. Use only short category names and try to only include each post in one category, or your URLs will get too long.

Yoast has a lot of [additional info and suggestions on using categories in your permalink structure](https://yoast.com/wordpress-seo-url-permalink/).